# How to Programically set the height and width of an ImageView

Tags: android

i am Programically  trying to add  imageViews into a Linear Layout as follows:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParamsTV = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(100, 100);
for( i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    LinearLayout llv = new LinearLayout(this);
    llv.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    ImageView row1 = new ImageView(this);
    row1.getLayoutParams().height=50; // getting error here
}
```

How to set the height and width of the ImageView and i want to add one more image view right over this imageView , how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(640, 480); // width , height 

row1.setLayoutParams(params); // row1 is your ImageView
```